# Rule in outlook to prevent sending email to individual

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-2013

Is there a way to specify a rule in Outlook Exchange to accidentally send an email to an individual that's in the group of addresses?

eg:

```
to: person1_good@example.com; person2_bad@example.com; person3_good@example.com
```

I know there's a way to block email coming in, but interested if there's a way to block email going out via a rule to: `person2_bad@example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Exchange Admin Center you can do it in the Mail Flow Section.

Mail Flow -> Rules -> Create a new rule -> Apply this rule if... the recipient address includes (enter the address) -> *Do the following.... delete the message without notifying anyone.

There are many other options available here to manage how mail is handled.

Comment: I don't believe I have access to the Exchange Admin Center.